# Cannot reach services exposed by docker containers on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, networking

I've been struggling with a strange problem on Ubuntu 18.04. I cannot reach services exposed by containers. I will show you on an example with nginx.

Starting the container:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm -d -p 8080:80 --name web nginx
```

docker ps shows:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
f09c71db299a        nginx               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   web
```

- listening is on *0.0.0.0:8080* as expected

But curl throws "**Connection reset by peer**":

```
$ curl -4 -i -v localhost:8080

* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:8080/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I used tshark to inspect a network traffic:

```
   $ sudo tshark -i any

   66 7.442606878    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 8080 → 47430 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=79 Win=65408 Len=0 TSval=4125875840 TSecr=4125875840
   67 7.442679088 172.16.100.2 → 172.16.100.1 TCP 56 80 → 37906 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
   68 7.442784223    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 8080 → 47430 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=79 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=4125875840 TSecr=4125875840
```

I see **RST** within the container(?). I have never had such an issue and I'm a bit lost how to solve it. Can someone help me out?

**UPDATE:** I used *docker inspect f09c71db299a* and it shows that:

- "Gateway": "172.16.100.1"
- "IPAddress": "172.16.100.2"

*172.16.100.1* it's my *docker0* IP address. It looks it rejects traffic from the container, right?

**UPDATE 2:** According to [NightsWatch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2198540/nightswatch)'s suggestion I checked if the host accepts connection on the 8080. Telnet says:

```
 ~$ telnet localhost 8080
 Trying ::1...
 Connected to localhost.
 Escape character is '^]'.
```

So it looks port is open but the request is blocked :/

Comment: check if the host machine accepts connection at port 8080, you can also try accepting connection at 80 ( -p 80:80 ) to check if the connection works

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. I checked it and looks fine:


~$ telnet localhost 8080
 Trying ::1...
 Connected to localhost.
 Escape character is '^]'.